# "Quotes "in" the titles", are backwards ""when"" nested or stacked

Tags: bug, status-declined, formatting, title

"Quotes "in" the titles" of text, are backwards when nested. However they don't get quotified from the double-apos in the body. So things look right in the body, but not in the rendered title or on the question-index page. I'd put this on MSO but I'm banned from asking questions there. Clearly the intent should be to render on the basis of the world boundary.

- Either double-apos should be typographically quotified everywhere, or nowhere.
- It should be rendered on the basis of the word boundary if `quote_count / 2 > 1`

Comment: Shog9, guess who the community respects more.. me, or you? Hint: I have more EXP than you here.

Comment: And, interestingly enough, you still have Diamond-Mod status.

Answer (score 6):

Out of all the questions posted on Database Administrators, only two have stacked quotes:

[ORA-04031: unable to allocate bytes of shared memory ("","","","")](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12008/ora-04031-unable-to-allocate-bytes-of-shared-memory)

[ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number with name "" too small](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7343/ora-01555-snapshot-too-old-rollback-segment-number-with-name-too-small)

...and both of those render correctly. Only *one* question has *nested* quotes:

[How do I resolve Postgresql error, 'no collation was derived for column "foo" with collatable type citext'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17609/how-do-i-resolve-postgresql-error-no-collation-was-derived-for-column-foo-w)

Given how rare this is, and how [easy it is to avoid or work around](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/quotes-in-the-titles-are-backwards-when-nested-or-stacked/648#648), I can't see a purpose to handling these cases differently.

Comment: So you admit that my logic would more often render the desired result, but you still reject the concept because it requires more work at StackExchange.. What does Jeff even pay you guys to do?

Comment: Actually, no - I haven't implemented or tested your logic to see if it breaks anything. So I don't know if the results are any more likely to be correct. I just know that - in the context of this site - there's precious little benefit.

Comment: Right, but in the context of every stack-exchange site my grand plan for quoting utopia could revolutionize the industry.

Comment: Technically in the case of the first example, it does the right thing here.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing it wrong. You can't nest quotes like that. The proper form is:

> "Quotes 'in' the titles", are backwards "when 'nested' or 'stacked'"

When nesting quotes, you switch from double to single quotes.

Comment: and when you need 3 levels of nesting? Or 4? Or 42?

Comment: @ypercube: To English.SE!

Comment: And, what if you're quoting an error message that has double-quotes in it too. How about addressing the problem rather than establishing a workaround? What's wrong with the suggestion as-is?

Comment: @EvanCarroll what's wrong with your question as it is now? The title is grammatically correct and the body contains a blockquote (using `>`) with the exact error message. Seems like a perfect fix to me!